spring boot tomcat 9 Cannot delete a temp file
I work with spring boot (2.0.6.RELEASE) and Apache Tomcat 9.0.72 Server. the os is windows server 2019 and I use jdk1.8.0_311 .
I try to upload files with this code :
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadMultipleFiles/{uid}")
    public List<UploadFile> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files,@PathVariable String uid) {
    
        return Arrays.asList(files)
                .stream()
                .map(file -> uploadFile(file,uid))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    


 @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile/{uuid}")
    public UploadFile uploadFile(@RequestParam("files")  MultipartFile files,@PathVariable String uuid) {
         try {
             log.debug("File : "+files);
             fileStorageProperties.setUploadDir("D:/"+uuid);
             fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir()) ;
              
             Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
                this.fileStorageService = new FileStorageService(this.fileStorageProperties);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Could not create the direeectory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
            }
        String fileName = this.fileStorageService.storeFile(files);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/api/upload-files/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();

        return new UploadFile(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
                files.getContentType(), String.valueOf(files.getSize()));
    }





  public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
        // Normalize file name
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

        try { 
          
            // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
            Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
            //add owners permission
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
                 
            Path targetLocation = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName);
            
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            return fileName;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not store file " + fileName + ". Please try again!", ex);
        }
    }
    

I have error in the server related to tmp file :
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\test-app\upload_a7b5769f_9936_4d4d_9e36_6e0537e042bc_00000001.tmp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.recycle(Request.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:441)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot delete C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\test-app\upload_a7b5769f_9936_4d4d_9e36_6e0537e042bc_00000001.tmp
    ... 13 more

I think the problem is related to spring boot version
or to input stream that is not closed.
so I should change my code to close the input stream but I didn't find the correct way to do this.
